# Display CFGRID Data Store in cfoutput

Tags: coldfusion-8, cfgrid

I am able to display the data store from a cfgrid selected row in a form.  When a row is selected, the contents of the form fields change based upon the selection.

What I would like to do is take a single element from the selected row and use it to dynamically change the name of the header of the form fields.  The specific data is being placed in a fieldset.

Here is an example:

Details for Title of the selected row <---Dynamic based upon cfgrid row selection.

form.data
form.data
form.data

With form data there is a bind to the grid.selectedrow.column name as {gridname.columnname}

However, I can't use a text form field because it messes with the div for the fieldset.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I hope, You mean legend value of a fieldset. 
Hook a rowclick event for your cfgrid & in that eventhandler change your legends innerHTML

Please check 
http://www.danvega.org/blog/index.cfm/2008/3/20/CFGrid-Event-Listeners